# Are there benefits to an xdmp map over structured xml?

Tags: xml, dictionary, xquery

I'm learning XQuery and MarkLogic.  I've come across a map, which seems to be like a hash in other languages, but it seems like you can do what you need simply with the built-in functionality of structured language.

Are there benefits to the map:map() over structured language?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maps have been added to the XSLT 3.0 working draft and some XQuery vendors have started to implement them in advance of their inclusion in the XQuery language.

There are a number of reasons they are needed. XML elements can't hold arbitrary values: for example the attribute of an XML element can't be a document or element node, or a sequence containing a string followed by two integers, or a function. In addition, because XML nodes have identity and parent information, copying them is an expensive operation, and (except within the limited scope of XQuery updates) you can't modify an XML tree without copying the whole thing. By contrast, even with a non-mutable map, modified copies can be made quite cheaply using deltas.

Incidentally, maps go by a vast number of different names in different languages. The terms "hash", "dictionary", "associative array", "object" are all encountered. The term "map" seems the one that is most common in modern functional languages. "Hash" strongly suggests an implementation, and it would be wrong to suggest that maps have to be implemented as hash tables. Other data structures such as red-black trees or finger trees may be more suitable.

Answer (score 2):

I see mainly two reasons:

- Storing the data in an XML fragment makes it necessary to copy the data. That can be costly, if you have a large amount of data. Maps should be in-memory.
- XQuery 3.0 makes function a first class citizen of XQuery, thereby you can use functions as value items in maps. This is impossible using XML.